# I would like to store all command-line arguments to a Bash script into a single variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-line-interface

Let's say I have a Bash script called **foo.sh**.

I'd like to call it like this:

```
foo.sh Here is a bunch of stuff on the command-line
```

And I'd like it to store all of that text into a single variable and print it out.

So my output would be:

```
Here is a bunch of stuff on the command-line
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
echo "$*"
```

would do what you want, namely printing out the entire command-line arguments, separated by a space (or, technically, whatever the value of `$IFS` is). If you wanted to store it into a variable, you could do

```
thevar="$*"
```

If that doesn't answer your question well enough, I'm not sure what else to say...

Answer (score 29):

If you want to avoid having $IFS involved, use $@ (or don't enclose $* in quotes)

```
$ cat atsplat
IFS="_"
echo "     at: $@"
echo "  splat: $*"
echo "noquote: "$*

$ ./atsplat this is a test
     at: this is a test
  splat: this_is_a_test
noquote: this is a test
```

The IFS behavior follows variable assignments, too.

```
$ cat atsplat2
IFS="_"
atvar=$@
splatvar=$*
echo "     at: $atvar"
echo "  splat: $splatvar"
echo "noquote: "$splatvar

$ ./atsplat2 this is a test
     at: this is a test
  splat: this_is_a_test
noquote: this is a test
```

Note that if the assignment to $IFS were made after the assignment of $splatvar, then all the outputs would be the same ($IFS would have no effect in the "atsplat2" example).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `$*` variable. It combines all command line arguments into one.

```
echo "$*"
```

This should do what you want.

[More info here.](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#POSPARAMREF)