# Accessing bash command line args $@ vs $*

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

In many SO questions and bash tutorials I see that I can access command line args in bash scripts in two ways:

```
$ ~ >cat testargs.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo "you passed me" $*
echo "you passed me" $@
```

Which results in:

```
$ ~> bash testargs.sh arg1 arg2
you passed me arg1 arg2
you passed me arg1 arg2
```

What is the difference between `$*` and `$@`?
When should one use the former and when shall one use the latter?

Comment: take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/842325/671366

Comment: static analysis in IntelliJ treats `echo "something $@"` as an error

Answer (score 542, accepted):

The difference appears when the special parameters are quoted. Let me illustrate the differences:

```
$ set -- "arg  1" "arg  2" "arg  3"

$ for word in $*; do echo "$word"; done
arg
1
arg
2
arg
3

$ for word in $@; do echo "$word"; done
arg
1
arg
2
arg
3

$ for word in "$*"; do echo "$word"; done
arg  1 arg  2 arg  3

$ for word in "$@"; do echo "$word"; done
arg  1
arg  2
arg  3
```

---

one further example on the importance of quoting: note there are 2 spaces between "arg" and the number, but if I fail to quote $word:

```
$ for word in "$@"; do echo $word; done
arg 1
arg 2
arg 3
```

and in bash, `"$@"` is the "default" list to iterate over:

```
$ for word; do echo "$word"; done
arg  1
arg  2
arg  3
```

Comment: Is there a possible use case, when `$*` or `"$*"`may be required, & the purpose cannot be served by `$@` or `"$@"`?

Comment: Also, is there a difference between `${arrayname[*]}` vs `${arrayname[@]}`?

Comment: Which version is more suitable for a "wrapper" script, where the scripts parameters need to become parameters to a new command?

Comment: @Segfault, in this case, always choose `"$@"` with the quotes.

Comment: This answer contains useful examples but in would be better if it also explained the mechanism behind them. *Why* does it work like this?

Comment: Instead of `for word ...` loop, you  could write: `printf "%s\n" "$*"` to be compared to `printf "%s\n" "$@"` and `printf "%s\n" $@`! (... or even `printf %s\\n "$@"` ;)

Comment: I wonder why bash is designed to behave like this... It seems quite strange IMHO...

Comment: bash is a strange language. In many ways I think it is constrained by compatibility with the 40+ year old Bourne shell

Answer (score 359):

A nice handy overview table from the [Bash Hackers Wiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20230325102835/http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams):

| Syntax | Effective result |
| --- | --- |
| `$*` | `$1 $2 $3 … ${N}` |
| `$@` | `$1 $2 $3 … ${N}` |
| `"$*"` | `"$1c$2c$3c…c${N}"` |
| `"$@"` | `"$1" "$2" "$3" … "${N}"` |

where `c` in the third row is the first character of `$IFS`, the [Input Field Separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_Field_Separators), a shell variable.

If the arguments are to be stored, [load them in an array variable](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005#Loading_values_into_an_array).

Comment: Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4824637/2192488), which includes quoted input. The input also matters!

Comment: Let's say I want to create a wrapper script that does nothing but mimic the functionality of the wrapped command. Which syntax should I use to pass the args from the wrapper script to inner command?

Comment: @MarinosAn use `"$@"` (with quotes). None of the other variants work

Comment: Thanks very much for such a clear explanation—for an obtuse explanation, see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html Bash documentation.

Answer (score 53):

**$***

> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the
>   expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word
>   with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of
>   the IFS special variable. That is, "$*" is equivalent to "$1c$2c...",
>   where c is the first character of the value of the IFS variable. If
>   IFS is unset, the parameters are separated by spaces. If IFS is null,
>   the parameters are joined without intervening separators.

**$@**

> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the
>   expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a
>   separate word. That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" ... If the
>   double-quoted expansion occurs within a word, the expansion of the
>   first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original
>   word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last
>   part of the original word. When there are no positional parameters,
>   "$@" and $@ expand to nothing (i.e., they are removed).

Source: [Bash man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

Answer (score 24):

$@ is same as $*, but each parameter is a quoted string, that is, the parameters are passed on intact, without interpretation or expansion. This means, among other things, that each parameter in the argument list is seen as a separate word.

Of course, "$@" should be quoted.

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#ARGLIST

Answer (score 3):

This example let may highlight the differ between "at" and "asterix" while we using them.
I declared two arrays "fruits" and "vegetables"

```
fruits=(apple pear plumm peach melon)            
vegetables=(carrot tomato cucumber potatoe onion)

printf "Fruits:\t%s\n" "${fruits[*]}"            
printf "Fruits:\t%s\n" "${fruits[@]}"            
echo + --------------------------------------------- +      
printf "Vegetables:\t%s\n" "${vegetables[*]}"    
printf "Vegetables:\t%s\n" "${vegetables[@]}"
```

See the following result the code above:

```
Fruits: apple pear plumm peach melon
Fruits: apple
Fruits: pear
Fruits: plumm
Fruits: peach
Fruits: melon
+ --------------------------------------------- +
Vegetables: carrot tomato cucumber potatoe onion
Vegetables: carrot
Vegetables: tomato
Vegetables: cucumber
Vegetables: potatoe
Vegetables: onion
```

Comment: Scientifically speaking, tomatoes are fruits.

Comment: You have right! "In botany, a fruit is the seed-bearing structure in flowering plants (also known as angiosperms) formed from the ovary after flowering."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit

Comment: @Randy: scientifically speaking, all fruits are vegetables (it's a synonym for "plant").

Comment: @CrisLuengo heresy! :)