# How to keep strings quoted in bash parameters

Tags: bash, parameter-passing, double-quotes, variable-expansion

I have a Bash script which passes patterns and switches to grep.

```
#!/bin/bash

foo() {
    grep $@ *.txt
}

foo $@
```

And, of course, `myscript SomeText` works but `myscript "Text1 Text2"` does not. Is there a way to keep the quotes when passing arguments from script to foo() and then from foo() to grep?

Note, that I cannot simply use eval and wrap the whole $@ before grep since it can also contain switches so I need to keep the original quoting as passed from the command line.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grep command looks incomplete, have you script like this with quoted parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x # for debug purpose only, comment out later

foo() {
    grep "$@" *.txt
}

foo "$@"
```

And call it like this:

```
./myscript "Text1 Text2"
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought I already tested your solution but I probably forgot to quote $@ in one of the calls.

Comment: @jackhab, the difference between quoted and unquoted is illustrated at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12316565/7552

Answer (score 2):

Simply quote the `$@`:

```
#!/bin/bash 

foo() { 
    grep "$@" 
} 

foo "$@"
```

This is a difference between `$@` and `$*`.