# Concatenate strings in multiple lines using bash

Tags: string, bash

Given a list of arguments, I am trying to produce a string looks like the following using bash script:

```
 - arg_1
 - arg_2
 - arg_3
 - arg_4
```

And here is my script trying to do this:

```
seeds=
for i in $*; do
  seeds=`printf "$seeds    - $i\n"`
done;
echo "$seeds"
```

However, when I run it with input `arg_1 arg_2 arg_3 arg_4`, the above script generates the following output, which apparently ignores my spacing and new-line character:

```
- arg_1 - arg_2 - arg_3 - arg_4
```

Can I know what did I do wrong in my script? or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting and whitespace is very [important](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html) in the shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for arg in "$@"; do
    seed="$seed    - $arg\n"
done
echo -ne "$seed"
```

Demo:

```
$ ./script.sh arg_1 arg_2 arg_3 arg_4
    - arg_1
    - arg_2
    - arg_3
    - arg_4
```

Comment: In addition, I am not trying to print them, but more importantly storing them in a string since I will later invoke `sed` to use them to modify a file.

Comment: @keelar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314451/accessing-bash-command-line-args-vs

Answer (score 3):

Like sudo_O says (and [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) would have pointed out), you should use `"$@"` rather than `$*` for the minimal fix.

You asked if there was a better way of doing it, though, and there definitely is. When given more arguments than necessary to fulfill the format string, `printf` will repeat the output as necessary. This lets us simply write:

```
printf "- %s\n" "$@"
```

Comment: +1 for SpellCheck however check the OP comments on my answer `I am not trying to print them, but more importantly storing them in a string`.

Comment: @sudo_O: That's easily changed: `seeds=$(printf "- %s\n" "$@" )` (although note that the final linefeed will be trimmed before it's stored in the variable -- if this is a problem, there are solutions but a bit messy).

Answer (score 1):

I think your script is too complex. I don't think you need command substitution here. May you try this one

```
seeds=
for i in $*; do
  seeds="$seeds\n- $i"
done;
echo -e ${seeds#\\n}
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems work except it introduces one additional new line at the beginning (although it's easy to fix that).

Comment: I changed it according to your needs

Comment: no only the first one. From bash's reference manual: `If the pattern matches the beginning of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern deleted`