# How to pass seperate arguments to an expect script?

Tags: bash, arguments, expect

I have an `expect` script that executes the commands given as arguments like this:

```
!/usr/bin/expect
spawn telnet ip
for {set i 0} {$i < $argc} {incr i 1} {
  set cmd [lindex $argv $i] 
  send "$cmd\n"
}
```

And I can call it with whatever commands I want to execute on the remote device e.g. `my_expect_script "cd /home" "ls" "mkdir mydir"`. I would like to have something executed before this script by default. My idea was to write another script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
do-something
my_expect_script "$*"
```

Now if I do so the `my_expect_script` seems to get only one argument. In my example only the `cd`part would be executed.
Is there a simple way to pass the arguments as seperate arguments but at once?

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12316565/2546460). I have to adapt the second script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
do-something
my_expect_script "$@"
```

I always thought `$*`and `$@` do exactly the same.

Comment: It's subtle but significant.