# Howto read result of command lspci each line as an element of array?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'd like to have video card information from my target system, no matter what it is. There are two lines returned from my current target system, and I'd like to treat each line as an element of array.
Using the code below, I got every word from lspci result rather than whole line which is what I need. Any idea?

```
myvideos=(`lspci | grep VGA`)
for video in ${myvideos[@]}
do
   echo "The $video"
done
```

The result returned from the code are:

```
The 00:02.0
The VGA
The compatible
The controller:
The Intel
The Corporation ....
```

What I need is :

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation
```

Thank you!

Comment: This is [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: I need an array for them, not just read a line, thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's part of what that page covers. Techincally that is [Bash FAQ 005](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005) but it is linked from 001.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. use [`mapfile`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-mapfile) to capture the output into an array.

   ```
   mapfile -t myvideos < <(lspci | grep VGA)
   ```
2. Absolutely crucial to [use quotes on the array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12316565/7552) in the for loop

   ```
   for video in "${myvideos[@]}"; do ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to do the same without using arrays:

```
lspci | grep VGA |  xargs -i echo The {}
```

or

```
lspci | grep VGA | awk '{print "The " $0}'
```