# Split string into (optional) chunks in bash, and pass parameters conditionally

Tags: bash, mongodb

I have a string that might be:

- `user:pass@host` // case #1
- `user@host` // case #2
- `host` // case #3

(It's a mongoDB connection string, if you're curious)

I need to end up with:

## Case #1: `user:pass@host`

- `$hostVar` -> `host`
- `$userVar` -> `user`
- `$passVar` -> `pass`

And then run:

```
mongodump --host $host -u $user -p $pass ...
```

## Case #2: `user@host`

- `$hostVar` -> `host`
- `$userVar` -> `user`
- `$passVar` -> (empty)

And then run:

```
mongodump --host $host -u $user ...
```

Note: the `-p` parameter to mongo is not passed.

## Case #3: `host`

- `$hostVar` -> `host`
- `$userVar` -> (empty)
- `$hostVar` -> (empty)

And then run:

```
mongodump --host $host ...
```

Note that `-u` and `-p` are not passed.

## So...

I am going insane because of the optional nature of the parameters. My first solution was a classic:

```
user=$(echo $DBHOST | cut -d : -f 1)
pass=$(echo $DBHOST | cut -d : -f 2 | cut -d @ -f 1)
host=$(echo $DBHOST | cut -d : -f 2 | cut -d @ -f 2)
```

However, if bits are missing, this completely breaks down.

I tried conditional parsing, based on the presence of `:`, but the result was... well, embarrassing to show here.

The second issue is then: is there a way to "maybe" pass parameters to a command without conditionals? Something like `hostParam="--host $host"` and then passing `$hostParam` would work?

ALL of this is because `mongodump` doesn't support mongo's connection string, and I have a setting variable in the format I showed in the config file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
# $conn holds the connection string

# this array will contain the parameters
params=()

if [[ $conn =~ ^(.+):(.+)@(.+)$ ]]; then
    params=( -u "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" -p "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" --host "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}" )
elif [[ $conn =~ ^(.+)@(.+)$ ]]; then
    params=( -u "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" --host "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" )
else
    params=( --host "$conn" )
fi

# call the command
mongodump "${params[@]}"
```

Comment: Jesus bash has evolved since my time... would you be able to tell me what that `params[@]` is...? The `BASH_REMATCH` is magic, I love it!

Comment: I know it says "don't just thank you", but... really, seriously thanks. Amazing, concise, to the point and gorgeous coding.

Comment: `"${params[@]}"` refers to the elements of the array `params` as a list of quoted arguments (similarly to how `"$@"` are the positional parameters with any quoting etc intact).

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12314451/7552) and its answers details the differences between `"$@"` and `"$*"` and  `$@` and `$*`, and the same conclusions can be reached about accessing the elements of an array `"${params[@]}"` vs `"${params[*]}"` vs `${params[@]}` vs `${params[*]}`