# What does run_command() { echo "+" "$@"; "$@"; } means in bash script?

Tags: bash, function, arguments

So I am new learning bash script and I came up with the following piece of code.

```
run_command() {
  echo "+" "$@"
  "$@"
}
```

I am confused on what "$@" means and why is it twice?

Thanks a lot for your time and have a great day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aagam Jain's got the answer. I will add some explanation that wouldn't fit in a comment section. I apologize for the verbosity.

Consider this example.

**Showing parameters given to a script**

test.sh:

```
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
```

Let's run this script and give it 2 parameters.

```
$> bash test.sh ls -l
```

Result:

```
ls
-l
```

First parameter `ls`, represented by `$1`, is echo'ed in the first line. Second parameter `-l`, represented by `$2`, is echo'ed in the second line.

**Bash manual - let's see what it says**

> ($@) Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one

See this: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters

How does that impact our example? Let's change test.sh a bit.

**Expanding parameters starting from one**

test.sh:

```
echo "$@"
```

Let's run it.

```
$> bash test.sh ls -l
```

Result:

```
ls -l
```

`$@` listed both parameters in the same line one after the other. If you had 5 parameters, they'd be printed one after the other.

Let's change test.sh a bit more.

**Adding a `+` to the echo**

test.sh:

```
echo "+" "$@"
```

Let's run it.

```
$> bash test.sh ls -l
```

Result:

```
+ ls -l
```

That means, a `+` appeared before both parameters were printed.

Change test.sh a bit more.

**Executing all provided parameters**

test.sh:

```
echo "+" "@"
"$@"
```

Let's run this.

```
bash test.sh ls -l
```

Result:

```
+ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 eapo users  0 Sep 23 19:38 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 eapo users 19 Sep 23 19:38 test.sh
```

Great. As the commenters and Aagam mentioned, the script printed out what it was going to execute (using `echo "+" "$@"`) and then executed the command. The "$@" basically is just doing `ls -lh`. Terminal just executes it as is.

Let's put a function in the script now.

**Adding a function in the script**

test.sh:

```
run_command() {
    echo "+" "$@"
    "$@"
}

run_command ls -l
```

Note that we are executing the function in the script itself instead of giving it on the command line

Let's run it.

```
bash test.sh
```

Result:

```
+ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 eapo users  0 Sep 23 19:38 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 eapo users 58 Sep 23 19:41 test.sh
```

Hope the examples walk you through how the script functions.

Comment: Up Vote :).
Awesome explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation!

Comment: Awesome. Good teamwork. @JennySmith although completely optional, you may want to give closure to your question by marking Aagam's answer as accepted and probably giving him an upvote also.

Comment: @JennySmith you might want to accept Aagam's answer as accepted rather than mine. Aagam answered first and was an accurate answer. Mine just had additional explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This prints the command and its output.

e.g.

```
run_command() {
  echo "+" "$@"
  "$@"
}

run_command ls

#output
#+ ls
#files_list_in_current_directory
```

Comment: But how is "$@" doing that? I am confused on what "$@" is.

Comment: @JennySmith see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314451/accessing-bash-command-line-args-vs. That'll lead you to learning about "$@"

Comment: Oh Sorry. `$@` holds the arguments passed to your function.

Comment: @AagamJain so it holds the arguments and the output as well?

Comment: @JennySmith `$@` is just the arguments. `echo "+" "$@"` runs the `echo` command to print a "+" followed by the arguments, and then `"$@"` by itself runs the arguments themselves as a command (and just lets output go to the usual place). So if you ran `run_command cp file1 file2`, it would execute `echo + cp file1 file2` and then `cp file1 file2`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks a lot for the explanation :D. I am just confused now on why "$@" acts in two different ways. For the first one it just acts like a string to let itself be echoed and for the second one, it actually executes the function with its parameters. Why is this?

Comment: @JennySmith great questions. This is the right answer, but for additional explanation beyond the comments I've added an answer that walks you through the process.