# How to assign the total number of lines in a file to the size variable for an array in a bash script?

Tags: arrays, bash, wc

i've been trying to get something like this to work for a while now but I keep running into little imperfection that mess up building my array.

#!/bin/bash

There are a total of four lines in this repo file

`repofile=~/Home/Documents/repoKali`

I type this into the command line

`wc -l < $repofile`

I get the following output

> 6

But when I type this

`SIZE=$(wc -l < "$repofile")`

I get this

> 6: command not found

I'm trying build an array that is as big as the number of lines in $repofile. I'm not sure why the commands work outside of variable assignment and not when I assign them to SIZE.
I mean the output changes! or am I just missing something?

Please Help. I'm trying to do something like this.

`readarray -s $SIZE < $repofile`

Comment: As an aside: There's no reason to use `<` for passing a file's content to `wc` - just pass the file (path) as an operand: `wc -l "$repofile"`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to initialize bash arrays with a size, just put values into the array.

The `-s` option for readarray is not for "size", it's for "skip":

> Options:
>   ...
>
> > -s count   Discard the first COUNT lines read

From a bash prompt, type `help readarray` for all the details.

---

This error `6: command not found` indicates to me that you're putting a space after the = sign: no spaces are allowed for variable assignment

```
SIZE= $(wc -l < "$repofile")
#....^
```

Comment: yeah that worked. I did

readarray repolist < $repofile

then

echo ${repolist[@]}

I got the output I was looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: Remember to always quote the array expansion: `"${repolist[@]}"` -- https://stackoverflow.com/q/12314451/7552