# Users who are logged on, in alphabetical order, printed on one line

Tags: bash

Users who are logged on, in alphabetical order, printed on one line.

What are the minimum amount of changes to get this to work because in a bash script?

this is the given script:

```
for name in $@
do
    who | grep -w "^name" | sed 's/ .*//' | uniq
done | sort | tr '\n' ' '
echo
```

Answer (score 3):

Single line commands:

```
who | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq | tr '\n' ' '
```

- `who`: list of logged in users.
- `awk '{print $1}'`: keep only the first word or each line, which is the usernames.
- `sort`: put the usernames in alphabetical order.
- `uniq`: remove duplicates.
- `tr '\n' ' '`: remove carriage returns, and replace them with spaces.

**Ex**

```
$ who
steve    tty7         Mar  5 16:25 (:0)
bernard  tty7         Mar  5 16:25 (:0)
sarah    tty7         Mar  5 16:25 (:0)

$ who | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq | tr '\n' ' '
bernard sara steve
```

---

Your code did `grep -w "^name"`, which tells `grep` to output the lines that start with "name".  *Not* the lines that begin with the *value* of variable "name".  For that you would need to do `grep -w "^$name"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
for name in "$@"
do
    who | sed 's/[[:space:]].*//' | grep -xF -- "$name"
done | sort -u | paste -sd ' '
```

- `$@` should always have double quotes on it (`"$@"`).  See [Accessing bash command line args $@ vs $*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12314451/4154375).  [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) correctly complains if double quotes are not used.
- `sed 's/[[:space:]].*//'` removes the first whitespace character, and everything after it, on every input line.  Using `[[:space:]]` instead of a literal space character means that the code will still work if the `who` output uses tabs as separators.  It may be easier to read too.  The `sed` command is run first to ensure that usernames occupy whole lines so it's easier to avoid spurious matches at the next pipeline stage.
- `grep -xF -- "$name"` searches for whole lines in the input that are the `"$name"` string.  The `-x` option forces matching of whole lines.  That prevents, for instance, the username `mary` matching the username `mary.jane` (a valid username on at least some Linux systems).  The `-F` option means that regular expression patterns in "$name" are treated as literal strings.  That prevents, for instance, the name `t.m` matching the name `tim`.  The `--` prevents a leading hyphen in `"$name"` being treated as a `grep` option.  No system that I know of allows usernames to have leading hyphens, but there's nothing to stop such an invalid name being provided as a command line argument to the code.  The `-w` option to `grep` wouldn't be useful here because valid names may contain non-word characters (e.g. `t.m`).
- `sort -u` takes the output of the `for` loop (an unsorted list of usernames, one per line, possibly with repetitions) and sorts it.  The `-u` option causes it to remove duplicates (like piping to `uniq`, but saves a process creation).
- `paste -sd ' '` puts all the lines in to input on a single line, separated by spaces (specified by the `-d` option and `' '` (space) option argument), and terminated with a newline character.  `tr '\n' ' '` would have a similar effect but it produces an unterminated line with a trailing space character.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
who | sort -k1,1 -u | awk '{u=u s $1; s=OFS} END{print u}'
```

That will output a blank-separated list of all logged in users, all on 1 line, with a terminating newline to make it a valid POSIX text file, and without an undesirable trailing blank char.