# how to expand bash function parameters inside function / fix shellcheck SC2294

Tags: bash, shellcheck

Assume a function that runs a command in another directory:

```sh
sub() {
  cd subdirectory
  eval "$@" || exit
}
```

I would like to be able to invoke this function with parameters that are expanded inside the subdirectory, e.g. `sub ls '$(basename $(pwd))'`

However, as the function is defined above, it does not pass shellcheck:

```
^-- SC2294 (warning): eval negates the benefit of arrays. Drop eval to preserve whitespace/symbols (or eval as string).
```

Obviously, if I remove the eval, then the parameter is not expanded and if I remove the quotes as well, then the parameter is expanded in the current directory. Which is not what I want.

I understand there are some suggestions in shellcheck's wiki, but I don't know how to make them work.

Is it possible to use eval correctly in this scenario -- without the downsides described in [SC2294](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2294) -- or do I need to ignore this rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `eval "$*"` instead of `eval "$@"`.  That will have exactly the same effect (assuming that `IFS` has its default value) and [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is happy with it.  See [Accessing bash command line args $@ vs $*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12314451/4154375) for details of `$@` versus `$*` (quoted and unquoted).

Use of `eval` is, justifiably, generally discouraged.  See [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/4154375).  Sometimes there's no better option though.

Answer (score 0):

> ... Drop eval ...

So drop it.

```
sub() {
  cd subdirectory
  "$@" || exit

  # I would do:
  if ! "$@"; then
     exit
  fi
}

sub sh -c 'ls "$(basename "$(pwd)")"'
```

> invoke this function with parameters that are expanded inside the subdirectory

Using `eval` is evil. Consider a different approach - define a function with the code that will be executed.

```
todo() {
   # properly escaped script
   ls "$(basename "$(pwd)")"
}
sub todo
```

---

And, overall, if this is for interactive use, and you know what you are doing and the problems with `eval`, just leave it and silence the warning. For example, watch arguments are run via `sh`, like `watch 'echo $(date)'`.

```
sub() {
    cd subdirectory
    sh -c "$*"
}
```

Comment: I tried this and the parameter was no longer expanded