# How do I deal with spaces in filenames for a wildcard parameter in a bash script?

Tags: bash, wildcard-expansion

I am writing a bash script that will take a list of filenames as an argument. It will generally be used with wildcards.

Right now, the script just prints the files:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $@
do
    echo "Processing $file" 
done
```

The problem is when using a wildcard, and the file list has filenames that contain spaces. For example, if I have two files `file1.jpg` and `file two.jpg`, and I run `./myscript.sh *.jpg` my output is

```
Processing file1.jpg
Processing file
Processing two.jpg
```

How do I make it recognize "file two.jpg" as one thing instead of two things? Note that the wildcard could be just `*` and files are not guaranteed to have an extension.

I am running this on a Mac, using GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21)

Comment: You need `"$@"`. This is an extremely common FAQ.

Comment: Thanks. It is hard to find with search because the results are flooded with how to do it for non-wildcard situations and how to do other wildcard things not related to this!

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid the duplicate I found is also less than ideal but some of the answers there discuss this solution.

Comment: See [Accessing bash command line args $@ vs $*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12314451/4154375).

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies the problem, and links to an explanation of how to fix it ([SC2068](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2068)).